# Autoloading utility functions

Tags: php, function

I have several functions independent from each other and I used to wrap them in one class so I could autoload them via `spl_autoload_register()`. But then my utility class is getting so big now it's almost 1000 lines.

Now I'm thinking of separating each function in to each class/file.

If you think this is a good idea what do you think is the best approach:

```
// load_foo.php
class load_foo
{
    public function __construct ($params,..)
    {

    }
}

// usage
new load_foo($params);
```

or

```
// load_foo.php
class load_foo
{
    public static function exec ($params,..)
    {

    }
}

// usage
load_foo::exec($params);
```

Comment: It's a bad idea in the first place to hijack the class system only to use it as a collection of functions.

Comment: @Radu I think OP realizes this now.

Comment: If the class is that big (legitimately that big) it may be possible to use inheritance to split it up into child objects that are more specific to their functionality. If you're just using it as an alternative to procedural functions, then it's a bad idea to use objects in the first place. (Hint: everything can be made into an object; you just have to stop and think a little bit first.) Looks like you're in for a major refactor, @IMB.

Comment: @Matt, I'm not sure he does, the question sounds like "what's the best way to split this big collection of unrelated functions in smaller collections of unrelated functions?"

Comment: @Matt It is legitimately that big. My primary reason is to autoload and save filesize loading. Rather than including them individually on each call or loading them all at once.

Comment: @Radu The answer is to step back, look at the code and start over, looking at the code and architecting it properly. Which is what I think OP is trying to do.

Comment: @IMB, by "legitimately big" I mean that the object was properly architected and is still huge, not that it's "really big".

Comment: @Matt, I completely agree with that.

Comment: @Matt I am not sure if inheritance is a good idea since the functions are literary independent and is not related to each other. Each function works on it's own.

Comment: Then you're in for a HUGE refactor. You're using OOP to do procedural programming, which is bad. Each object should represent a concrete "thing" or idea, and its member functions should represent "doing something" with that "thing" or idea.

Comment: @IMB, loading, parsing, generating the AST, etc, for 10000 functions only for calling one function is much slower than loading only the functionality you need, even if it's in multiple files. If it's performance you're after, you're much better off sticking to what you're comfortable with (which seems to be functions) and categorizing the finctionality in separate chunks of related content, then spreading it over relevant files, each containig relates functionality.

Comment: @Matt I agree, the functions are used procedurally and the OOP concept is never used. So I guess the only way I can do it properly is to either load everything at once or individually as needed.

Comment: @Radu Yeah, that is why I am suggesting the above proposal so I don't load 1000 lines of functions all at once. But then if I load only the function I need manually via `include` then it's gonna be quite an `include` "nightmare" in code.

Comment: That's pretty much the situation, OP.

Comment: @IMB, not as much as you think. If you split the functions by related functionality, then you shoudln't need to load many files when working with them.

Comment: @Radu As mentioned all functions are independent, no function is related to another.

Comment: @IMB, so you have hundreds of functions that are not in any way related to one another? By related I mean something like: functions that process strings, functions that use the filesystem, etc, a broad generalization.

Comment: @Radu Well they are somewhat related but I don't like the idea of grouping them since they should act independently.

Comment: @IMB but you're grouping them right now... All together... Even if they are independent of each other, think of this as grouping them in packages of functions, each package being responsible of providing the broad functionality that describes it (say, the "string utility" package). This is common practice.

Comment: @Radu I agree but it's actually more of a pet peeve for me. I prefer `Utility::foo()` than `Utility_Group::foo()` and besides some functions fit in more than one group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since apparently you don't use the notion of "objects" then it's best if you use the "static" option, load_foo::exec($params);

That being said, I believe that "separating each function in to each class/file." is overkill, you'll wind up with too many files and classes. Even if the functions are unrelated (as your comments suggest), try putting them in a few files which you load with your autoloader.

On a different note, you can use an accelerator, like APC or xcache. These will keep a pre-compiled version of your code, considerably minimizing the performance impact of loading files.