# PHP autoloading verses utility functions in a single class file

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I have a a class file with a lot of utility functions written as static methods. There are about 85 such functions. This file is included with every script, even though typically only a few of the functions are used for each script.

This is similar to the situation posed in the question at [Autoloading utility functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850923/autoloading-utility-functions).

The combined file is 168k in size and has just under 5000 lines. Opcache is enabled.

My question is the trade off between a single file load that needlessly increases the footprint of each script but only has one file to load, verses autoloading the separate class files, which would only load the ones that are needed. The tradeoff is the memory footprint of the single large file verses the much smaller footprint, but multiple loading.

I realize that the size of the functions and the relative number of them used bears on the situation; and that benchmarking is one way to make this decision. Yet I am wondering about any general guidelines that may be applicable.

EDIT

The 85 functions are for the most part relatively commonly used functions on many pages. The alternative design choices are the following:

1. Have a single file with all the functions in one.
2. Break them into one per file (in some cases very closely related functions would be grouped together so would not strictly be a "one-per-file").
   a. Go through the trouble of deciding which of them need to be included for each script.
   b. Part "a" is just theoretical--would actually at that point use autoloading.

Again, the question is  the trade-offs between "all-in-one" with a single file to load and large footprint, verses smaller footprint but multiple loads. I would expect that as a rule there would be 6 - 10 having to be loaded for each script. So not too excessive.

Comment: One single file containing 168kb of helpers? That seems excessive. What are those helpers? iIdon't see why you would even need 10% of that, tbh (but that's just me, and I don't know what they are). Either way, it would make much more sense to break them up in to multiple classes. Even if the helpers are "unrelated" to each other, they can probably still be grouped in some logical way, like "array helpers", "string helpes" and such (or any other grouping that make sense). If not just for the foot print, it would probably make maintenance easier.

Comment: Grouping the functions and then moving them into separate files is probably a better way to do it with a helper file being that big. You can make use of `require_once` if you need to include other files easily where those functions overlap. With that said, `require_once` *could* also slow it down if it's a simple function being called many times.